# compass position on Top right corner on google map v2 in android

Tags: android

Anyone please help me, I want to set compass button on top right corner on the Google map. I have wasted my lot of time but i didn't find any answer that can help me. 
How can I achieve this with the Google maps ?
Any suggestions?

Comment: still no actual answer to this question? :( -- you could try this approach http://blog.kozaxinan.com/2013/08/how-to-change-position-of.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `Compass` is coming at left side corner in Google maps V2. You just set`.setCompassEnabled(true)`.

```
myMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
```

and also compass icon appear only if you rotate the map to not align to north.

Comment: Have you seen latest google map there compass icon shown on right top corner with new icon.. and its look so great..

Comment: @bharat7777 yaa off course but it's up to latest Map.....Check it up [developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity?hl=it](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity?hl=it)

Comment: Feeling bad very bad.. how i will make it.